# How to install vim 7.4a with homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I installed vim with `homebrew` on my macbook

`brew install macvim`

but the version I wish was 7.4a, the latest beta release, how can I install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me,

`brew info macvim`

told me this:

> macvim: stable 7.3-66, devel 7.4b-BETA-69, HEAD

And as such, I would have to do this:

`brew install macvim --devel`